# .NET C# Thread exception handling

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I thought I understood this, and am a bit embarrassed to be asking, but, can someone explain to me why the breakpoint in the exception handler of following code is not hit?

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
        Thread testThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(TestDownloadThread));
        testThread.IsBackground = true;
        testThread.Start();
    }

    static void TestDownloadThread(object parameters)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        try
        {
            webClient.DownloadFile("foo", "bar");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Error downloading: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 4 new answers had been posted when I was typing!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're creating a thread, setting it to be a *background* thread, and starting it. Your "main" thread is then finishing. Because the new thread is a background thread, it doesn't keep the process alive - so the whole process is finishing before the background thread runs into any problems.

If you write:

```
testThread.Join();
```

in your `Main` method, *or* don't set the new thread to be a background thread, you should hit the breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks for answering a "dumb" question

Answer (score 1):

Your thread is a Background thread (you set it so yourself).  This means that when the application completes, the thread will be shut down without being given chance to complete.

Because your `main` has no further content, it exits immediately and both the application and your thread are terminated.

If you were to add a `testThread.Join()` call then your thread would complete before the app exited and you'd see the exception caught.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your background thread isn't started before Main exits - starting a new thread may take a while. Since the additional thread is a background thread it is terminated when Main exits.

For demo purposes, you could have your main method wait - e.g. on user input. This would allow the background thread to start running.

Answer (score 0):

Since the new thread's `IsBackground` is true, it won't prevent the process from terminating. At the end of `Main()` the only foreground thread terminates, shutting down the process before the other thread gets that far.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the main thread is ending before the worker thread. Try adding

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

at the end of your `Main` method.